# Dual monitor, permission issue

Tags: permissions, multiple-monitors

I had a dual monitor configuration going on for quite some time. One day, after moving the computer to another location and reconnecting everything, it changed such that I saw everything in double (being very much sober), I think it's called the 'mirrors' config. Anyway, from there on, there was nothing to be done through the system settings gui to change it back, as it wouldn't allow me to save any modification. The error I get when clicking 'save' is : 
"Failed to create file /home/me/monitors.xml.xxxxxx. Permission denied", xxxx being a random code, changing everytime.
However, I can save all the configurations I want just fine by using the terminal, in my case:

```
 xrandr --output DVI-I-1 --right-of VGA-1
```

So I do have a workaround and this is therefore a question more out of curiosity. What could possibly have changed to make it impossible to do it through the gui and still letting me change the config using xrandr without being root? I'm having a hard time believing it could have anything to do with disconnecting/reconnecting the monitors... Any idea? Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `monitors.xml` file goes under `/home/me/.config/monitors.xml`.  You may try to remove it, if it's there and check the `.config` directory permissions.

Comment: Of course! I had no writing permissions in the .config directory. How could I miss that!? How it got this way I don't know but that is definitely where the problem came from. What it still doesn't explain is why it would let me change the settings using xrandr. But that's good enough. All good now, thanks! (don't have enough reputation yet to vote you up, sorry.)

Comment: @cenna75 `xrandr` doesn't mess with config files.  It's a dynamic configuration tool. :)

Comment: That makes sense. There is so much I have yet to understand about these things :) Fortunately there is this place!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what happened, but try to add the command to a startup script. This will take care of it after you login.
As for why this happened, perhaps an update of some sort. Connection/Deconnection has probably nothing to do with it (although ya never know)

Comment: Yes, that was my move, I added it to my .xprofile. It's still annoying, however, to fail to understand the permission problem :)